# Alternatives to using rendered attribute with PrimeFaces( for AJAX Updates)

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a page which needs dynamic rendering capabilities depending on the radio button selected - I am using the rendered attribute on my page controls and managing this via the backing bean for the page - when a radio button gets selected the page gets refreshed depending on the rendered attribute I selected in the managed bean( via an AJAX call of course) - the following is a sample of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
<h:selectOneRadio valueChangeListener="#{myBean.onValueChange}" 
id="radioButton1"
tabindex="10" 
value="#{myBean.displayTypCd}"
<f:selectItem itemValue="A" itemLabel="Option1" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="B" itemLabel="Option2" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="C" itemLabel="Option3" />
<p:ajax event="click" process="@this"
listener="#{myBean.onValueChange}" 
update=":f:myContainer" />
</h:selectOneRadio>

<p:selectOneMenu rendered="#{myBean.selectMe}"
id="myId" 
effect="highlight"
value="#{myBean.element1}"
<f:selectItems value="#{Collection.element}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

So this works fine - I am able to re-render parts of my page but there is a flicker - I am trying to see if the same can be achieved from the client side and if anyone has had any success with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the rendered attribute using javascript. The rendered attribute is for server side use only. In order to control the rendering on the client side, you can use Javascript to do that as below

```
function(){
   var component = document.getElementById('formid:componentid');
   component.style.display = 'none';    -- to hide it
   component.style.display='inline';    -- to render it
}
```

Or if there are multiple components you can wrap the components in a div and use the same code as above for the div.